# How to use asyncio with django rest api framework just the way jquery promises work so that responses don't need to wait

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, python-asyncio

I am on python 3.7 with django 2.2.3 running. I want a solution with asyncio so that the api can just call the async function & return the response without waiting just the way we do things with the jquery promises. the definition `my_coro` is just for example. I will be running `moviepy` functions that usually require 40-50 seconds to complete. I don't want the api to wait that long for sending out the response. I am also confused on how to handle the thread pool. how to use thread pool here? because I intend to make the moviepy iterations fast as well. So how to create a pool for handling `my_coro` calls?

```
async def my_coro(n):
    print(f"The answer is {n}.")

async def main(): 
    await asyncio.gather(my_coro(1),my_coro(2),my_coro(3),my_coro(4))

class SaveSnaps(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format = None):
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            return Response({"response":"FORBIDDEN"}, status = 403)
        else:
            try:
                asyncio.run(main())
                return Response({"response": "success"}, status = 200)
            except Exception as e:
                return Response({'response':str(e)}, status = 400)
```

**Update :**
I tried using celery. but as I won't be using periodic tasks & actually the method I need to make asynchronous receives a blob array as parameter. celery's `task.delay` is giving me an error because tasks expect serializable params. So I am back to square one on this. I am not sure whether I should stick to the threading solution or something else.

**Update :** I forgot to share what I did at last. I shifted to `celery`. but since `celery`'s `task.delay` expect `serialized params`, I moved the `blob` saving part to a synchronous method which after completion, hands over the moviepy tasks to the `celery` run task.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the data you are passing?
What do you mean with Blob Array?

Comment: I meant a `FormData` object containing 1000-1200 png `blob` objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, **asyncio** is going to process your code concurrently, but your application is still going to wait for the execution of **asyncio** to be done, then it continues execution inside your app.

If you want your app to run the code in the background and continue execution, similar to **Promises** in JS, you need to consider using **Job Scheduling** using [**Celery**](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for example, or something similar.

This is a simple [Guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html) for using Django with Celery.

Comment: Ok I am going for celery after all. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this issue, and this is what I've found.

The compatibility issues between DRF and asyncio are mostly at the Router layer of DRF.

If you override the `as_view` in a ViewSet you will run into errors where the Router is expecting either a callable or a list of callables.

This means there are 2 categories of solutions:

1. Skip / Customize DRF routers.
2. Wrap the routers URLPattern.

This is what I've had the most success with so far, perhaps others can provide improvements on it.

```
router = OptionalSlashRouter()

router.register( ... )


def _async_wrapper(func):
    async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        kwargs['loop'] = loop
        return await sync_to_async(func)(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


urlpatterns = [
    url(urlpattern.pattern,
        _async_wrapper(urlpattern.callback),
        name=urlpattern.name)
    for urlpattern in router.urls
]
```

I previously tried just wrapping the callables in the `sync_to_async` function, but this didn't seem to allow the views themselves to get the event loop.

However, with this pattern, I was able to call `loop.create_task(some_coroutine)` from inside a drf viewset.

There are a lot of downsides to this pattern, of course.  For one thing, you have to pass the event loop around if you want to use it.

I may end up just removing the drf routers entirely.  But this is obviously a drastic step in most projects as there are often a lot of urls managed by DRF routers.

Comment: so even if I use asyncio.run(async_method) within my view it will block the asgi event loop, right?